# MariaDB / Columnstore engine Memory getting chocked

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf, columnstore

we have installed mariadb along with columnstore engine and from the last few weeks we are facing memory chocking issue where memory getting chocked and all our DML/DDL operations are getting stuck, after restarting the services it gets fixed.

```
below are the stats :

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             15           2           7           0           5          12
Swap:             4           0           4


[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket          = /opt/evolv/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir         = /opt/evolv/mariadb/columnstore/mysql/db
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 0
# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
#thread_concurrency = 8
thread_stack = 512K
lower_case_table_names=1
group_concat_max_len=512
infinidb_use_import_for_batchinsert=1
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8192M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 100M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
```

Comment: Please provide the `Columnstore.xml` contents

Comment: @rickJames Columnstore.xml file attached on the below link

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H5s6Zqz2N5-QrLTBrRsNd-7sm6LYDKQPwu7YwWradJo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @WilsonHauck

my.cnf and rest of the information attached in the below link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CyS1i1sfWCZoocuW2XI5ABk7CzkXG9xlVTBzU4I7ElQ/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JYzdqN0iXtIicpO3h3MpJbgzefsgS6zyf1egG6Wv7BE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While debugging i have found WriteEngineServ is using alot of memory around 70%

Comment: If that is really `show GLOBAL status`, then you have a very idle server.  Perhaps it was actualy `SHOW STATUS`?

Comment: @RafayPervaiz Suggestions, REMOVE from my.cnf [mysqld] section to allow defaults to work for you, sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size, read_rnd_buffer_size. Change thread_cache_size from 8 to 32. Enable max_heap_table_size=64M so it is the same as tmp_table_size. Let us know of your progress. We need the other data requested, including SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an analysis of the `VARIABLES` and (suspicious) `GLOBAL STATUS`; nothing exciting:

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.1.26-MariaDB
- 15 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 03:04:25; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.
- Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Uptime = 03:04:25; Please rerun SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after several hours.

Are you sure this was a SHOW GLOBAL STATUS ?

`key_buffer_size` is excessively large (3G).  If you don't need MyISAM for anything, set it to 50M.

Check `infinidb_um_mem_limit` to see if it makes sense for your application.

Suggest lowering `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 2G until the "choking" is figured out.

**Details and other observations:**
`( (key_buffer_size - 1.2 * Key_blocks_used * 1024) / _ram ) = (3072M - 1.2 * 0 * 1024) / 15360M = 20.0%` -- Percent of RAM wasted in key_buffer.
-- Decrease key_buffer_size.

`( Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size ) = 0 * 1024 / 3072M = 0` -- Percent of key_buffer used. High-water-mark.
-- Lower key_buffer_size to avoid unnecessary memory usage.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size / _ram ) = 6144M / 15360M = 40.0%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free * 16384 / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 392,768 * 16384 / 6144M = 99.9%` -- buffer pool free

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( expire_logs_days ) = 0` -- How soon to automatically purge binlog (after this many days)
-- Too large (or zero) = consumes disk space; too small = need to respond quickly to network/machine crash.
(Not relevant if log_bin = OFF)

`( long_query_time ) = 5` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

**Abnormally large:**

```
read_buffer_size = 32MB
Acl_database_grants = 780
Acl_proxy_users = 4
Acl_users = 281
```

**Columstore.xml**

95% of *all* memory??

```
    <MemoryCheckPercent>95</MemoryCheckPercent> <!-- Max real memory to limit growth of buffers to -->
    <DataFileLog>OFF</DataFileLog>
```

I guess this is not relevant, since it is commented out??

```
    <!-- enable if you want to limit how much memory may be used for hdfs read/write memory buffers.
    <hdfsRdwrBufferMaxSize>8G</hdfsRdwrBufferMaxSize>
    -->
```

Keep in mind that MySQL, other than Columnstore, is consuming a lot of memory:

```
    <TotalUmMemory>25%</TotalUmMemory>
    <TotalPmUmMemory>10%</TotalPmUmMemory>
```